# SSRS DateTime Parameters

Tags: reporting-services

Please Could someone help me on the below?

I want to set the DateTime Parameters to Last 24 hrs i.e if the current date time is 14/07/2016 14:30 then my

Start Date : 13/07/2016 14:30 
End Date : 14/07/2016 14:30

Thanks
Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to sort this, in case if someone wants the answer. Here is the one:

Start Date : `=cdate(format(DateAdd("d", -1, now),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))`

End Date : `=cdate(format(DateAdd("d", 0, now),"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))`

Comment: You could change End Date to just use "now" rather than the whole `dateadd(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried ? DateAdd("d", -1, yourDateTime)

(code not tested)

Comment: No, this gives us previous Day but I am looking exact last 24 hrs from the time the report is run